# An electron placed between two negatively charged plates

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

Let us assume that an electron with initial velocity $v$ is located between two fixed, negatively charged plates. Now I know that the force applied on the two electrons would cancel each other out, but would the electron still travel between them with the same velocity $v$? For simplicity sake lets assume that the plates are infinitely long and and have same charge density on both plates.

Comment: You mean infinite sheets of charge, correct?

Comment: And what do you mean by similar? Do the plates have identical negative charge densities?

Comment: @BobD Yes, they may have thickness hence called them plates. And yes they have same charge densities.

Answer (score 3):

> Now i know that the force applied on the two electrons would cancel
>   each other out, but would the electron still travel between them with
>   the same velocity v?

Yes. The electric field for an infinite sheet of charge is the the same at all points away from the sheet. The electric fields of two such parallel infinite sheets of charge of equal charge density will cancel between the plates for a net field of zero. An electron placed between will experience a net force of zero and not accelerate (its velocity will not change).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As the net force on the electron is zero, it will continue moving with the same velocity. However, this is only if the plates are infinite. If they are not, then the electron will be pushed out.

Comment: This is a low quality post. Please add more details or it might be deleted.